# install gradle 2.2.1 for manually use

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

My first installation of Android Studio was with no internet connection so I set everything to run as if I was offline. I now have an internet connection that is not real reliable at times I live very remote. I have updated to AS 2.2.1 I would like to know how to reconfigure Gradle to 2.2.1 so I can function offline as well as on line.

1.This is what I think I should do 
under project structure set Gradle Version to 2.2.1

2.in settings for gradle set Service dir path to
C:/Java/astudio/gradle/gradle-2.2.1  (it now says gradle-2.14.1)

and yes I put all my AS stuff in the folder under C:/Java

So now the real confusion

under astudio gradle-2.14.1 wrapper dist I have all these gradle folders

Gradle-2.4-all
Gradle-2.8-all
Gradle-2.10-all
Gradle-2.14.1-all

3.So I need to download gradle-2.2.1-all.zip

where do I put it under  a folder called gradle 2.2.1 under astudio/gradle

the gradle-2.2.1-all.zip is massive

I need some step by step information I am more than a little unsure of my steps above. Can I set AS so it will include gradle build updates when AS updates?
My Enviroment Path does not include GRADLE_HOME